# R - download website including all .css, .js, pictures etc

Tags: r, curl, wget

Say i want to download the page of r-Bloggers.com.
If i press Ctrl+S in Chrome, an html file will be downloaded plus a Folder with 58 files (.css, .js, Pictures, etc.)

I would like to do the same from R.

I found an answer and wrapped it into `system()`: `system("wget --page-requisites https://www.r-bloggers.com/")`

does not give me the 58+1 files.

Same for:

```
download.file(url = "https://www.r-bloggers.com/", 
              destfile = "try", mode = "wget", extra = "--page-requisites")
download.file(url = "https://www.r-bloggers.com/", 
              destfile = "try.html", mode = "wget", extra = "--page-requisites")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because by default Wget will only attempt to download items from the same domain. However, this website loads everything from different hosts.

You need to use the `--span-hosts` flag to allow Wget to access files from different hosts